# Is there a way to fetch Apache environment variables in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, apache-config

I am serving the react application through Apache. For SSO (Single Sign On) , I am using Apache based authentication. So the flow is whenever a user hitting the application URL , Apache will take care of getting the user information from SSO server and then it will redirect to home page. now I am having user information's in Apache response headers. Is there a way we can access these information in react js.

Note : I am not using any middleware application layer. Only React Js application.

Comment: So do you just have an html page that references react scripts and other custom scripts and an apache server returning that page after authentication? If so, then I don't think so.